# pass string on marker click

Tags: android, eclipse, google-maps-markers, android-json

I'm trying to pass Strings comes from json array I tried this code

```
     mMap.setOnMarkerClickListener(new OnMarkerClickListener() {
         public void onInfoWindowClick(Marker marker) {
         Toast.makeText(Newtab.this,"MARKER clicked", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
     }

    @Override
    public boolean onMarkerClick(Marker arg0) {

         Intent intent = new Intent(Newtab.this, SingleItemView.class);
         try {
             intent.putExtra("DESCRIPTION",obj.getString("DESCRIPTION"));
         } catch (JSONException e) {
             // TODO Auto-generated catch block
             e.printStackTrace();
         }

         // Start SingleItemView Class
         intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_ANIMATION);

         startActivity(intent);
         return false;
    }
});
```

but it passes only the last String from the array.

How can i pass the string which related with the specific marker to another activity ?

Comment: I can't see where you pass it as an array. The only place you set something is intent.putExtra("DESCRIPTION",obj.getString("DESCRIPTION")); and there you are passing a String, not an array

Comment: @Lukas yes I'm passing a string which comes from json array..my code only passes the last item from the array but what i need is pass the specific String object from the array. I already did view the title of each marker correctly from the array but i couldn't pass the same marker title to another activity. Sorry i know it's confusing process i wish it's clear now. thanks